# Runtime error -killing process either internal or external

Tags: c#, process

I have an exe ( Lets say A) which is responsible for sending emails to employee.
  At certain point may be because some error is not handled it throws a runtime error  as dialog box below .

"An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in MainApplication.exe" .

This stays as it is unless someone goes into the server and re-starts the application.
 I understand that by doing error handling this can be taken care still i want alternative solution to kill this process automatically and re-start it again.

I made another application B -  System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            process.StartInfo.FileName = @".....\MainApplication.exe";

and i was trying to find out if any runtime error has occurred then i could kill the process and start it all over again.

1) Is there any provision in exe A code which could kill the process itself and remove this dialog box automatically ?
 2) If not possible then can Other application B be utilized to capture and kill the process.

Any other suggestion is also welcomed!
Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with watchdogs is that they themselves are prone to failures. If you hit unhandled exception in app A, what makes you think that you won't hit same condition in application B?

What you should look into is to properly hook the unhandled exception events:

- [`AppDomain.UnhandledException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [`Application.ThreadException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [`WindowsFormsApplicationBase.UnhandledException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.applicationservices.windowsformsapplicationbase.unhandledexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

The proper way to handle these events, and which event applies to which case, is a rather lengthy topic. Read the links above for more details. Also read about [`Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.setunhandledexceptionmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

By catching these unhandled exception you can suppress the default dialog behavior by exiting explicitly. Traditionally there was also a registry key, see [How to turn off/disable the .NET JIT Debugging Dialog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToTurnOffdisableTheNETJITDebuggingDialog.aspx) but hooking the unhandled exception handler events is a better approach.

Comment: Thanks Guys for the valuable input. Much appreciated Richard you are right that this has to be run under server. I will do this as well as permanent solution.

Comment: One thing to consider with these (otherwise) unhanded exceptions is why they occurred: is the state of the process still valid? Unless you are clear all related state is reset after the exception you could just be doing anything. At best you will hide minor defects, at worst you'll corrupt what was valid state.

Answer (score 1):

If `A.exe` is a Windows Service (ie. to implement in .NET its main class derives from [`ServiceBase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.aspx)) then you can configure it to be automatically restarted by the system. (See the Recovery tab of service properties in `services.msc`).

For anything running long term in Windows a Service is the best approach, but if not written as such it may require a significant rewrite.

Alternatives:

- Use the scheduler to run something to see if `A.exe` is running, if not start it. This is easiest if only one instance of `A.exe` at any time.
- In the final (outermost) exception handler of `A.exe` start a new instance before exiting (and logging the failure).

But both of these should be seen as work-arounds pending implementing as a service.